# trying to create a do while loop for birth years

Tags: java, validation, loops, while-loop

This was the question.

Write a block of Java code, containing a do/while loop, that will read in a person’s year of birth. The year of birth must be a value larger than 1900, but smaller than 2016, else the user will receive an error message. The loop must continue to prompt the user until a valid value is entered.

This was my answer

```
 private static double saveYears() {
    double birthYear;
    do {
     try {
          birthYear= Double.parseDouble(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("enter year you were born"));
     }
     catch (NumberFormatException e) {
        birthYear= -1;
     }
     if (birthYear> 1990 || birthYear< 2016) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Invalid number birth year.");
     }
    } while (birthYear<1990|| birthYear> 2016);

    return birthYear;
}
```

Is that the correct answer?

Comment: `Is that the correct answer?` You tell us. Does it work? I'm guessing not. a) you use 1990 instead of 1900. b) if year > 1900 or < 2016 will "catch" every possible number (1 is < 2016 tick. 3000 is > 1900 tick. 1900 < 2016 tick)

Comment: Why is birthYear a double?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the OP should know if the code is working or not.

Answer (score 3):

Firstly I'm going to assume that you meant 1900 instead of 1990 in the if and while statements.

You're close, but if you look at your if and while statements they're actually testing for different things. If you change your if statement to match the while statement, you'll be correct.

```
private static double saveYears() {
  double birthYear;
  do {
    try {
      birthYear= Double.parseDouble(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("enter year you were born"));
    }
    catch (NumberFormatException e) {
      birthYear= -1;
    }
    if (birthYear < 1900 || birthYear > 2016) {
      JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Invalid number birth year.");
    }
  } while (birthYear < 1900 || birthYear > 2016);

   return birthYear;
}
```

Update: 
You could also do this if you don't want to check the birth year twice in the one loop.

```
private static double saveYears() {
  double birthYear;
  while(true) {
    try {
      birthYear= Double.parseDouble(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("enter year you were born"));
    }
    catch (NumberFormatException e) {
      birthYear= -1;
    }
    if (birthYear >= 1900 && birthYear <= 2016) {
      break;
    } else {
      JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Invalid number birth year.");
    }
  return birthYear;
  }
```

Comment: Note: This is assuming you wanted to include 1900 and 2016 in the valid number range. If not, you would need to change the equality statements.

Answer (score 0):

Your Condition check is wrong use,use `less than/greater than and =` to loop again for 1990 and 2016.

```
while(birthYear <= 1900 || birthYear >= 2016);
```

And there is no need of `double`,use `int` which is more than enough and restrict to 4 digits(which is according to specification 1900 or 2016 -> not more than 4 digits)

Answer (score 0):

You are using `(birthYear> 1990 || birthYear< 2016)` which means,

1. all values greater than 1990 will pass this condition
2. all values smaller than 2016 will pass this condition
3. from 1 & 2, basically all the years will pass this condition

Changing operator `||` with operator `&&` will fix your problem. Also consider these points:

1. Check if 1990 and 2016 are inclusive values or exclusive values. It will determine where operators `<`&`>` should be used or operators `<=`&`>=` should be used.
2. Why `double` for birth year?
3. You have checked the same condition twice, which is error prone. Reduce condition to one place like:

   ```
       int birthYear = -1;
       boolean isYearInvalid = true;
       while (isYearInvalid) {
           try {
               birthYear = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("enter year you were born"));
           } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
               //LOG or PRINT
           }

           if (birthYear > 1900 && birthYear < 2016) {
               isYearInvalid = false;
           } else {
               JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Invalid number birth year.");
           }
       }
   ```